# pyodbc SQLGetdata can't handle values larger than 4096 bytes

Tags: odbc, amazon-redshift, pyodbc

I am struggling to propose a fix to `redshift odbc 2.x` for when `pyodbc` is trying to return values larger than 4KB. If I do:

```
import pyodbc    
query = 'a' * 5000
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Amazon Redshift ODBC Driver (x64)}; Server=srv.amazonaws.com...')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(statement)
val = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
```

The value of `val` is curropted beyond 2046 characters.(It is half the 4KB coz it decides to process WCHAR but let's not consider that, for now). Naturally I don't get my 5000 characters.

Looking at the code of [ODBC](https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-odbc-driver/blob/main/src/odbc/rsodbc/rsutil.c#L1982) and [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/blob/master/src/getdata.cpp#L70):

I see that `pyodbc` initially assigns 4KB buffer (`cbAllocated=4096` and `cbUsed=0`)and invokes SQLGetData.

Then, ODBC populates 4KB. And also reports the actual size via `cbData`(say 5000).

pyodbc then reallocates buffer to 5000, sets `cbUsed` to 4KB and repeats SQLGetData:

`ret = SQLGetData(cur->hstmt, (SQLUSMALLINT)(iCol+1), ctype, &pb[cbUsed], (SQLLEN)cbAvailable, &cbData);`

In short, pyodbc *expects* ODBC to continue writing the remaining bytes.

But, I don't see ODBC keeping any `state` to resume its writing `cbUsed` from bytes away from the beginning og the buffer!. In another words, I just see ODBC receiving another request for SQLGetData and a pointer to write into:

```
SQLRETURN SQLGetData(  
      SQLHSTMT       StatementHandle,  
      SQLUSMALLINT   Col_or_Param_Num,  
      SQLSMALLINT    TargetType,  
      SQLPOINTER     TargetValuePtr,  
      SQLLEN         BufferLength,  
      SQLLEN *       StrLen_or_IndPtr);
```

Is ODBC expected to be stateful? How can I know which chunk of the data has to be written?

Comment: pyodbc itself can definitely handle values larger than 4096 bytes, and ODBC is "expected to be stateful" in that the [documentation for SQLGetData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetdata-function?view=sql-server-ver16) specifically says that "It can be called multiple times to retrieve variable-length data in parts." Also, I find it difficult to believe that the Redshift ODBC driver, which is already at version 2.0.0.3, fails to work with values larger then 4096 bytes.

Comment: The source code for the driver shows that it is calling `char_utf8_to_wchar16()` so it should be returning the strings as UTF-16, which is the default for ODBC. You can verify that with a little test program [like this](https://gist.github.com/c707bdd73d2fb862c3161d5b0fb569ca).

Comment: @GordThompson My first problem was I didn't know ODBC can be stateful. Next, I couldn't find the respective state in the code. So I just created one of my own, an offset to resume the write-to-buffer from where it left. It works. Still, I am trying to find a structure/variable that might have been previously created for such purpose; so as not to reinvent one extra. Any clues?